# Accessing Built-In Excel Ribbon Button State

Tags: c#, excel, ribbon

I'm experimenting with some custom ribbons in excel, and once of the behaviors I want to try and achieve is to mimic the built-in excel ribbon disabled/enabled states. I.e. If I'm viewing a ChartSheet or if I'm in edit mode, most of the ribbon tabs/buttons grey out.

Is there a way I can read the enabled states off something like the Chart's Ribbon Tab group?

In my research, I haven't been able to find something that does this. The closest thing I've found is overriding the existing ribbons and encasing them in your own custom controls using the "startFromScratch" value, but this feature is more for me to control the visibility of built in tabs, which I don't need.

Thanks